# USQL Using Code Behind in table valued function

Tags: u-sql

- I want to use a code behind function in a TVF table valued function in USQL. Is this possible ?
- I did not want to register the assembly since the function is very specific to the TVF and all it does is some formatting of input strings.

**Code Behind**

```
using System;

namespace Transform
{
    public class Formatter
    {
        private static DateTime DefaultDateTime = DateTime.Parse("1/1/2004");

        public static DateTime ToDateTime(string date, string format)
        {
            ...
        }

        public static DateTime? ToNullableDateTime(string date, string format)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

**Table Value Function Uses**

```
SELECT
            rec.id,
            rec.name,
            Transform.Formatter.ToDateTime(rec.effectiveDate,  "yyyyMMdd"),
            Transform.Formatter.ToNullableDateTime(rec.expirationDate, "yyyyMMdd")
```

The function compiles correctly. however when i run it it gives a runtime error saying that it does not recognize the token `Transform.` the namespace in which the code behind is defined

Currently I using a workaround in place of the code behind. However the function would be much much more readable if I could understand how to use it.

Comment: When you use codebehind file in a VS project, the tool automatically registers the assembly for you under a temporary name. In the underlying system there is no way to access user defined code without registering it as an assembly. The VS simplification only works for a USQL file and an usql.cs file that are paired together with the same name in the solution. Is your function in the codebehind file associated with the usql file where your TVF is defined?

Comment: Yes, I am using a USQL project in VS2015. I thought the same but even calling the function locally was giving me same issues

Comment: If you can email me at  bigdatatools at Microsoft.com, maybe we can debug your case more quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why code-behind does not work for TVFs is that the TVF needs to have all the name resolution and references inside the TVF's body. External dependencies (like the code behind header) do NOT leak into the function body.

We have added a new feature (next release notes will cover it) that gives you the ability to specify a light-weight function variable inside the TVF. E.g., something like (I am using TryParse as an example):

```
CREATE FUNCTION f() RETURNS @res AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @myfunc Func<int,string> = (f) => f.ToString();
    DECLARE @TryParseInt Func<string,int?> = (s) => {int i; var b = Int32.TryParse(s, out i); return b? (int?) i : null;};

    @res =
    SELECT @myfunc(1) AS intcol,
           @TryParseInt("42") AS stringcol
    FROM(
        VALUES
        (
            1
        )) AS T(x);
END;

OUTPUT f() TO "/output/f.csv" USING Outputters.Csv();
```

If you want to be able to reuse the function variable, you should be able to add the function variable declarations to a PACKAGE and then import the PACKAGE inside the table-valued function.